# Custom assembler syntax rules using regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a custom Assembler in Java for the 6502 microprocessor instruction set, obviously one of the main parts of an assembler is checking the syntax of the assembly program is valid before it can be converted into byte form.

So far I have worked out the following rules that will all need to be checked for each line of the assembly program

```
All instructions must be three letters long and match an instruction in the instruction table.

Branch labels cannot contain any characters aside from alphanumeric

Operands cannot contain symbols outside of "( ) $ # , + -"
Opening parentheses in operands must be closed. 
Operands can only contain one pair of parentheses
$ and # must be followed by numeric characters in operands.
Commas must exist between a value and a value OR a parenthesis and a value i.e. (xxx,yyy) or (xxx),yyy
```

I am coding the assembler in Java, and as such I was thinking about using regex patterns in order to check the validity of the above rules. Is this something that regex can be used for? I have used regex in the past but usually just single checks and nothing as extensive as this.

I'm not asking anyone to work out the regex patterns that could be used for these rules (although I would be grateful if anyone could as I really have no idea how to do some of them), I just want to know if checking these rules is something that is possible with regex.

Comment: Now that you have two problems, you better get used to trying out ideas here: https://regex101.com/ (That being said, I don't think you are ever going to work out a regex for the entire set; most such parsers are a number of if statements for this reason.)

Comment: Checking the input ahead of time will work, but it may be easier to just start processing it as an interpreter and throw an error if it encounters an issue with the input

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression can check that a string contains exactly 3 letters but it can't tell you if it exists in a table.

Regular expression can check that a string contains only alphanumeric characters.

Regular expression can check that a string only contains certain symbols.

Regular expression can count the number of opening parenthesis and closing parenthesis but cannot tell you if each opening has a matching closing.

The last three rules can also be checked via regular expression.

See javadoc for class [`java.util.regex.Pattern`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

For example, regex for first rule is `\p{Alnum}{3}`